# Specify that addIn doesn't work in Office 2013

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office-2013, office-2016

When submitting our addIn we got the following message back:

> If you do not support 2013 SP1 because you are using an API only available in 2016/Online, you must put these apis in the requirements tag in your manifest.

Our addIn does not work in Office 2013 since it uses both WordApi and ExcelApi (When opened in Word and Excel accordingly) which is not available in Office 2013.

Therefore we tried to specify in our manifest file that our addIn requires WordApi 1.1 by adding this to the manifest file:

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

However, when we add the requirement of WordApi then the addIn doesn't show up in PowerPoint and Excel and vice versa.

How do we specify that the addIn is not available in Office 2013 without having to create separate manifest files for each office Host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your manifest contains Word API (or any host specific API) then it will not show up in other clients.

If your add-in is designed to work in multiple clients, and requires an API not currently supported in Office 2013, please include these details in the test notes of your next submission. Should the validation team need any additional information to resolve the issue, they will reachout to you at the email address on record to discuss how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're tag is correct. I don't have a solution but perhaps something to try. I've read that the location of the Requirements Tag matters. I put my requirements tag above the  tag.

The article [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest][1] discusses validating your xml file with office-toolbox. You run the command "npx office-toolbox validate -m MANIFEST_FILE" (see the article for full details). When I run this validation command on my manifest which has ...

````
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>```

It returns 

```Validation: Passed
Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:
  - Excel for iPad
  - Excel 2016 for Mac
  - Excel 2016 or later
  - Excel Online```

The key here being that it recognizes that it is only valid for Excel 2016. We've been using this to identify when our tags are working without having to submit to MSFT.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest
````